# how to get the google refresh token with oauth2

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0

im trying to obtain an refresh token from google but it comes as undefined i have found that google doesn't send a refresh token only access token
but i couldn't figure out how to obtain the refresh token

here's my code

```
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/google/callback",
    },
    async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      
      try {
        let user = await GoogleUser.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value });
        if (!user) {
          
          user = new GoogleUser({
            googleId: profile.id, 
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            profileSetupComplete: false,
          });
          await user.save();
        }
        const info = {
          accessToken: accessToken,
          refreshToken: refreshToken,
        };
        return done(null, user,info);
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  async (req, res) => {
    const authCode = req.query.code;
    const accessToken = req.authInfo.accessToken;
    const refreshToken = req.authInfo.refreshToken;
   
    try {
     
      let user = await GoogleUser.findOne({ email: req.user.email });

      if (!user) {
        
        user = new GoogleUser({
          googleId: req.user.googleId, 
          email: req.user.email,
          profileSetupComplete: false,
        });
        await user.save();
      }
      console.log(refreshToken);
      res.cookie("access_token", accessToken, { httpOnly: false });
      return res.redirect("http://localhost:3000")
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error handling Google OAuth callback:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
  }
);
```

i find it difficult to deal with the refresh token from google the code is working for the access token but access token is short lived as i heard so must have a way to refresh the access token when it's expires